# How to use dropdownlist to insert the date and time into access data base(ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Year Month Day Hr Mm are the dropdownlistID

the system said this line has error "com.ExecuteNonQuery();"

here is my code Thanks

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|ISE2001.accdb";

    string cmdstr = "insert into Booking(PID,SID,P_DATE,P_Time) values(@PID,@SID,@P_DATE,@P_time)";        
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
    int Y = Convert.ToInt32(Year.SelectedValue);
    int M= Convert.ToInt32(Month.SelectedValue);
    int D = Convert.ToInt32(Day.SelectedValue);
    int Hr = Convert.ToInt32(Hour.SelectedValue);
     int Mn = Convert.ToInt32(Min.SelectedValue);
    DateTime thedate = new DateTime(Y,M,D);
    DateTime time = new DateTime(Hr,Mn)
    con.Open();

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", PID.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", SID);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_DATE",thedate)
    com.Parameters.Add("@P_DATE", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = thedate;
    com.Parameters.Add("@P_DATE", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = time;

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    Literal1.Text = "Success Booking";
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what error you get but looks like you forget to add value to your `@P_time` parameter in your command.

Maybe your

```
com.Parameters.Add("@P_DATE", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = thedate;
com.Parameters.Add("@P_DATE", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = time;
```

should be

```
com.Parameters.Add("@P_DATE", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = thedate;
com.Parameters.Add("@P_time", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = time;
```

??